# How to 'sleep' a Brainf_ck program?

Tags: brainfuck

Is it actually possible to make a Brainfuck code/program to 'sleep' for, say, x seconds or similar?

Surely looping over a big number until it goes down to 0 can't be it now, is it? It would probably not be really reliable or consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such operator, nor is there a way to reliably delay the program, considering the plethora of interpreters (and respective efficiency statistics) available. However, you may be interested in some different but similar languages that do have the capacity to sleep:

- [Alarm Clock Radio](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Alarm_Clock_Radio)
- [BFEnet](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BFEnet)
- [Delvs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Delvs)

Comment: @JeromeJ Yeah, sorry. There _are_ only 8 commands--there's not a lot to miss ;)